# Custom line breaks in Tidy break Django HTML files

Tags: vim, tidy

Currently I'm using [Tidy](https://api.html-tidy.org/tidy/tidylib_api_5.2.0/index.html) to format my code in Vim 8.2 using *ale* fixers. Everything is working, but while working with Django HTML files I need to have custom line breaks which Tidy doesn't let me.

My HTML code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/home/css/font-awesome.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/home/css/main.css">
<script src="/static/home/js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
{% block extrahead %}{% endblock extrahead %}
{% block extrastyle %}{% endblock extrastyle %}
```

After formatting I get

```html
<link href="/static/home/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/static/home/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/static/home/js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script> {% block extrahead %}{%
endblock extrahead %} {% block extrastyle %}{% endblock extrastyle %}
```

Tidy removes the breaks I added and reformats the correct code too.  And that causes an error in Django (`Invalid block tag on line 5: 'endwith', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?`).

Tidy line width is `99` and it's filling all lines, if there wasn't any block element (I mean Tidy block tags which cause line breaks) and it ignores my custom breaks and re-writes those lower than 99 char line too.

Here is my Tidy configuration file:

```
indent: auto
indent-spaces: 2
wrap: 99
markup: yes
show-warnings: yes
uppercase-tags: no
new-inline-tags: cfif, cfelse, math, mroot,
  mrow, mi, mn, mo, msqrt, mfrac, msubsup, munderover,
  munder, mover, mmultiscripts, msup, msub, mtext,
  mprescripts, mtable, mtr, mtd, mth
new-blocklevel-tags: cfoutput, cfquery
new-empty-tags: cfelse
sort-attributes: alpha
replace-color:yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make Tidy output a newline using HTML comment tag `<!-- -->` as follows

```html
{% block extrahead %}{% endblock extrahead %}
<!-- @tidy -->
{% block extrastyle %}{% endblock extrastyle %}
```

which outputs

```html
{% block extrahead %}{% endblock extrahead %} <!-- @tidy -->
{% block extrastyle %}{% endblock extrastyle %}
```

Just avoid it being removed accidentally.

Comment: wow! thanks, using a empty block element(`<!-- -->`) really helped as I couldn't find any other solutions.